# how can I show tvItem from model class in my toast by concatenation?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-recyclerview, android-toast

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
            holder.tvItem.setText(itemList.get(position).getmTitle());
            holder.imgFlag.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getmImage());
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You Clicked: " +, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You Clicked: " + holder.tvItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or you can pass the value directly:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You Clicked: " + itemList.get(position).getmTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: it is not showing data which is displayed in text field

Comment: @InformationHub so, you want to display title from your model for the specific position? Try to debug that line with `holder.tvItem.setText` and see what you get there

Comment: brother I solved it by +itemList.get(position).getmTitle() way.

Comment: @InformationHub that's also possible, but the question was how to show tvItem view text and not just the value passed to it :) I have updated my answer to cover both cases